# Is it a security risk to allow CSRF token to be sent in body OR header?

Tags: security, csrf, csrf-protection

Most CSRF solutions seem to insist that the CSRF token is sent as part of the POST data.

In my situation the data being sent is json, and I don't control what is sent (and I don't want to start messing with the json). So, I'm thinking of sending the CSRF token as a header. However, there are legacy parts of my application that would still need to be able to send the token in the body (e.g. submits from html forms).

So my CSRF protection would have to allow the request if a valid CSRF token appeared in the body OR a header. Is this a security risk, compared with insisting that the token is in the body?

Comment: [security.se] might be a better choice for this question

Comment: Downvoter care to comment and help me improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSRF is about make a unsuspicious user post data to a server where the attacker believes the user is logged in.

The idea behind the protection, is that the server associate a token to your session, and sends it to you as a cookie and as payload requirement. Then when posting something you send the token in the payload, and as cookie. Therefore the attacker cannot guess what token is in the cookie or the session. If the server receives a post with two different tokens, it will be rejected.

I think it would be fine to put the payload token in a header, as long it is not "Cookie" or any other header that is "remembered" and sent automatically by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

There won't be any security risk if you send a CSRF token in header. Just make sure that the value of this header changes everytime the client requests a page i.e it should be a random number. Also, your web application on client side should send this header back to the server, so that the server can match the value of header sent to the client with the value of the same header received from the client's response.

Answer (score 0):

Sending CSRF in request header is more secure.

CORS doesn't check same-origin policy for the form tag requests, which means if somebody managed to get the CSRF token then he can send the post request by using form tag from different domain (origin)
but in case of sending the CSRF in request header, the form tag cannot send request header, he has to use javascript (fetch() or XmlHttpRequest()), in this case the CORS will prevent him because he is sending from different domain (origin).

This defense relies on the same-origin policy (SOP) restriction that only JavaScript can be used to add a custom header, and only within its origin. By default, browsers do not allow JavaScript to make cross origin requests with custom headers.

below, is quoted from https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers

If this is the case for your system, you can simply verify the presence of this header and value on all your server side AJAX endpoints in order to protect against CSRF attacks. This approach has the double advantage of usually requiring no UI changes and not introducing any server side state, which is particularly attractive to REST services. You can always add your own custom header and value if that is preferred.

This technique obviously works for AJAX calls, but you still need to protect form tags with approaches described in this document such as tokens. Also, CORS configuration should also be robust to make this solution work effectively (as custom headers for requests coming from other domains trigger a pre-flight CORS check).

Answer (score 0):

Just to put a significant technical perspective on this:

As far as I know, returning a CSRF token in a header requires the whole form be sent by AJAX, fetch or axios. This might involve a significant rework of the client and backend for some sites, especially if many parts of a page have to be updated as a result of a request that would normally result in a simple regeneration of the whole page using the changed data.

Thus it requires JavaScript, which may not be required otherwise.

Such extra information may be updated breadcrumb paths if the request changed the owner hierarchy, or various details updated if the status of an entity was changed.

A hidden form field can be a simple piece of a HTMP template that is added to every form, and would be a lot simpler to implement.